# Is there a way to switch back into a werewolf from being a vampire without DLCs?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there a way to switch back into a werewolf from being a vampire without DLCs? And is there a way to be both (also without a DLC) in Skyrim? I am playing on the Xbox 360.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How often can I change my mind about vampirism or lycanthropy?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/103448/4797) and/or [How exactly does lycanthropy work? Does it mix with vampirism?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/34905/4797)

Answer (score 1):

On a console there is no way in the base game to become a werewolf again if you cure yourself.

It is also not possible to be both a werewolf and a vampire at the same time.